# how to send the JSON also from the PHP API

Tags: php, android, json, api, parse-platform

I'm  sending a text push from the php API code successfully, but I wonder how to send the JSON also from the PHP API

My problem is that when I send JSON from the PHP API code it received like like a "message" type.

When i send the same JSON code from the parse control panel it works fine 
I so some hint to send "uri" key in the data, but it didn't help.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

this is the PHP code that i'm using

```
<?php

$APPLICATION_ID = "gggggggggggggggg";
$REST_API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
//$MESSAGE = "your-alert-message";

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $errors = array();
    foreach (array('app' => 'APPLICATION_ID', 'api' => 'REST_API_KEY', 'body' => 'MESSAGE') as $key => $var) {
        if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
            $errors[$var] = true;
        } else {
            $$var = $_POST[$key];
        }
    }

    if (!$errors) {
        $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';

    if(strstr($MESSAGE,"{")){ //json
        $data['data_type']='json';
        //$MESSAGE =  json_decode($MESSAGE);
     }
//,               'uri' => $MESSAGE 
     $data = array(
            'channel' => 'test1',
            'type' => 'android',
            'expiry' => 1451606400,
            'data_type' => 'json',
            'data' =>array(
               'alert'=> "the link2",
               'uri' => $MESSAGE 
            ), 
         'uri' => $MESSAGE
          ); 

//var_dump( $data );die;
    //if(strstr($MESSAGE,"{")) //json
        //$data['data_type']='json';

    $_data = json_encode($data); 
 //var_dump( $_data );die;

        $headers = array(
            'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data)
        );

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    //    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
    }
}
?>
```

---

In the parse.com website there is a tool that you can send PUSH and in this tool you can send push with 2 types: plain text, or JSON.

it's look like that

[image]

When I try to send push with this parse.com tool in both types it works fine and I get the push properly

But, when I try to send to push from my PHP API code as a "JSON" I always got it as a "plain text"

What am I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Question isnt really clear...

Comment: i explained it again

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your JSON structure for example i want to send this:

```
{
 "data": {
    "date": "2015-12-09",
    "message": "and when you open this we will show you a message.",
    "title": "6 Notice Click On It :)))",
    "url": ""
   },
"is_background": false
}
```

and in your **php** you should send like this:

```
$data = array(
     'where' => '{}',  // send to all users
    // 'channels' => '{my_channel_name}',
    'data' => array(
        'is_background'=>false,
        'data'=>array(
            'date'=>'2015-12-09',
            'message'=>'and when you open this we will show you a message',
            'title'=>' Notice Click On It',
            'url'=>''
        ),
    ),
);
```